# amCharts Map with Bubbles on lat log coordinates

Tags: javascript, dictionary, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

It's possible to create exactly this kind of map:

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-bubbles/

but instead of positioning bubbles using the coutry ID doing it via latitude and longitude coordinates? I need to place a bubble for each city that i have data so, probably, more than one bubble per country.

I have a data structure like this:

```
Array (
        "name" => $row["city"],
        "latitude" => $row["latitude"],
        "longitude" => $row["longitude"],
        "value" => $row["count"],
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same struggle, managed to solve it.

So the data you assign to the image series need the properties `latitude`, `longitude` and `value` so that the bubble can be placed and the size can be determined.

`imageSeries.dataFields.value` will be assigned the `value` property from your data, while `imageTemplate.propertyFields.latitude` and `imageTemplate.propertyFields.longitude` will pick up the `longitude` and `latitude` from your data.

The function is written in JavaScript, looks a bit like below:

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
import am4geodata_worldLow from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldLow";

/* This is what the data looks like  
[
  {
    latitude: 48.856614,
    longitude: 2.352222,
    value: 100,
    title: "Paris",
  },
  {
    latitude: 40.712775,
    longitude: -74.005973,
    value: 200,
    title: "New York",
  },
  {
    latitude: 49.282729,
    longitude: -123.120738,
    value: 1000,
    title: "Vancouver",
  },
];
*/

const setupBubbleMap = ({ elementId }) => {
  let amChart = am4core.create(elementId, am4maps.MapChart);

  let title = amChart.titles.create();
  title.text = "[bold font-size: 20]Hotspots[/]";
  title.textAlign = "middle";

  amChart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
  amChart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

  let polygonSeries = amChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
  polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
  polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
  polygonSeries.nonScalingStroke = true;
  polygonSeries.strokeWidth = 0.5;

  const polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
  polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{title}";
  polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;

  let imageSeries = amChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
  imageSeries.dataFields.value = "value";

  let imageTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
  imageTemplate.nonScaling = true;
  imageTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
  imageTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";

  imageSeries.data = data;

  let circle = imageTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
  circle.fillOpacity = 0.7;
  circle.fill = am4core.color("#B27799");
  circle.tooltipText = "{title}: [bold]{value}[/]";

  imageSeries.heatRules.push({
    target: circle,
    property: "radius",
    min: 4,
    max: 30,
    dataField: "value",
  });

  imageTemplate.adapter.add("latitude", function (latitude, target) {
    let polygon = polygonSeries.getPolygonById(target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
    if (polygon) {
      return polygon.visualLatitude;
    }
    return latitude;
  });

  imageTemplate.adapter.add("longitude", function (longitude, target) {
    let polygon = polygonSeries.getPolygonById(target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
    if (polygon) {
      return polygon.visualLongitude;
    }
    return longitude;
  });

  return amChart;
};

export default setupBubbleMap;
```